# How to make CardView Visible beyond the BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android

I am trying to this design for practice [image: sample picture]

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border">
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/defaultimg"
                        android:elevation="10dp"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

but I ended up with this
I tried elevation also but i got not gettings the view

[image: result i got]

how to do this design?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, the imageview has to be the part of bottomsheet. What you need is to set the content with the background at an offset half of the imageview height vertically. This will give you the effect you are looking for.
First of all ,BottomNavigationView isnt bottomsheet. BottomNavigationView is the bar that you see at the bottom of the app that take you places in app.

The Layout Would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           android:background="#800"
           android:elevation="10dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/imageView3"/>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="0dp"
                                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                                   app:elevation="5dp"
                                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                                   android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                   android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    />
    <!--Put your scrollview here and remove the view-->

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Card view has a higher elevation than your imageview. So you need to make sure that the card view is set to an elevation lower than the imageView.
For ImageView use android:elevation and for cardview user app:elevation
YOu can find more about it here https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, I edit question with my code in it, can u please verify it